# Executing javascript in python when condition is met

Tags: javascript, python, tornado

I have a webchat application which is running on python, I'm trying to run a different javascript function for each room, something similar to what I've done with the "active" class in css.

```
<li {% if room == 1 %}class="active"{% end %}><a href="/room/1">Room 1</a></li>
```

Here's my attempt at creating a solution:

```
<li {% if room == 1 %}click="myFunction()"{% end %}><a href="/room/1">Room 1</a></li>
```

Basically, when someone visits room 1, the myFunction() javascript will be executed. Any ideas as to how one could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on that this is working exactly how you want:

```
<li {% if room == 1 %}class="active"{% end %}><a href="/room/1">Room 1</a></li>
```

Then to make the JS example work you want:

```
<li {% if room == 1 %}onclick="myFunction()"{% end %}><a href="/room/1">Room 1</a></li>
```

Notice that it's `onclick` not just `click`. If you were using `addEventListener` it would just be `click`, but when putting an event listener on an element directly like that, it's always (to the best of my knowledge) preceded by on, hence: `onclick`.

Comment: Hey, my javascript for some reason isn't being executed. Any reasons can you think of? It's probably the .click attribute I added: `div.addEventListener('click' function myFunction {
    return a * b;
}
document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML = myFunction(4, 3););`

Comment: There's no errors in the console, the javascript works but I think it's that the onclick isn't able to call the function because of the "div.addEventListener('click'", so I took it out and it worked but not because it was called by the onclick.

Comment: I would assume that `div.addEvent...` is for a `div`, which shouldn't affect an `li`. The best way to debug something like that is by using `console.log` to track where the code stops.